# Check selected menuoption in Office UI Fabric React's drop down component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, office-ui-fabric

I want to show the selected menu option as checked in the drop down. How can I do that?

Here's the code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown";
import * as styles from "./dropdownMenu.scss";
import { ResponsiveMode } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/utilities/decorators/withResponsiveMode";

export class DropDownMenu extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.size}>
        <Dropdown
          placeHolder="Select an option"
          id="timeFilterMenu"
          ariaLabel="Select a time filter for the analytics"
          defaultSelectedKey="B"
          options={[
            { key: "A", text: "Last 7 days" },
            { key: "B", text: "Last 28 days" }
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what it renders:
[no checkmark on currently selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNiWy.png):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `multiselect` attribute.

Eg:

```
<Dropdown
     multiselect
     placeHolder="Select an option"
     id="timeFilterMenu"
     ariaLabel="Select a time filter for the analytics"
     defaultSelectedKey="B"
     options={[
        { key: "A", text: "Last 7 days" },
        { key: "B", text: "Last 28 days" }
     ]}/>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**First add two methods onChange and onRenderOption**

```
<Dropdown
      placeHolder="Select an option"
      id="timeFilterMenu"
      ariaLabel="Select a time filter for the analytics"
      defaultSelectedKey="B"
      options={[
        { key: "A", text: "Last 7 days" },
        { key: "B", text: "Last 28 days" }
      ]}
      onRenderOption={this.onRenderOption}
      onChange={this._onChange}
    />
```

**On Change method add option selection logic**

```
_onChange = (
        event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
        selectedOption: IDropdownOption,
      ) => {
         selectedOption.isChecked = !selectedOption.isChecked 
         this.forceUpdate()
      }
```

**And then add onRender method logic**

```
private onRenderOption = (option: any) => {
        return (
          <>       
            <div className={option.isChecked ? 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--CheckMark' : ''}>
              {option.text}
            </div>
          </>
        );
      };
```

Note - Your code may change as per your requirement.